# PHP with ADOdb logical comprators

Tags: php, adodb

Hi everyone i have a problem with the logical comparators in php when i use ADOdb
Because when i do a select in a table with for example a CI, the resault is never NULL and i can't just verify if the person exist before the insert

CODE

```
<?php
include('inc/php/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
$db = ADONewConnection('mysql'); # eg. 'mysql' or 'oci8', 'postgresql' 
$db->debug = true;

// Establecer datos para comunicarse con el Gestor de Bases de Datos.
$server   = "localhost";
$user     = "x";
$password = "x";
$database = "xs";

// Traemos cositas del formulario de index.php
//$user=$_GET["username"];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ci = $_GET["username"];


$db->Connect($server, $user, $password, $database) or die ("Se pudrio todo !");

$sql = "SELECT ciInterno_Persona_ciPersona FROM internos WHERE ciInterno_Persona_ciPersona = '".$ci."';";
                $rs = $db->Execute($sql);
                /////////////////////////    
                    if($rs){
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO registrointernos VALUES ('', '0', '" .$fecha."', '".$ci."')";
                        $db->Execute($sql);
                                        }else{
                                               echo '<script language="javascript">alert("CI doesn't exist");</script>';
                                            }
$rs->Close();
$db->Close();

?>
```

The problem is that the result of RS is always true even when i put a CI that doesn't exist in the table

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `$db->Execute($sql);` returns derived class of `ADORecordSet` if query executed successful (documentation [here](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#execute)).

You have to do something like:

```
$rs = $db->Execute($sql);
$rows = $rs->GetRows();
if (!empty($rows)) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Or you can use `$db->GetRow($sql)` instead `$db->Execute($sql)`.

Comment: But i don't wanna take a row, i just want one specific value , which have to be the ci if it exist, and if doesn't exist , just nothing

Comment: @CodeSoBizarre You can try `GetCol` with limit 1, but it will be also array... I haven't found function in ADODB which returns only 1 scalar value, so you  have to deal with array(

Comment: Yea bro , you are right thanks for your awnsers. to solve the problem i put  if($rs->fields(0)) in the if sentence , so it works now , ;).

Comment: @CodeSoBizarre Awesome! Glad, you found solution!

Answer (score 0):

Solved , thanks for the answers.

CODE********

```
$sql = "sqlSentence";
$rs = $db->Execute($sql);
if($rs->fields(0)){
}
```

---

The solution is that you have to take what sql returns, choose the position and do the logical comparison.
so it is saved in $rs but $rs is like an array so you have to put the position in my case 0 . and its work perfectly